# Increment integer field in database when WHERE needs to be dynamic

Tags: wpdb, sql

I have a database column called "upvotes". I have another column called "userid".

I would like to increment the value in the "updates" column where the userid matches the dynamic variable I'm providing.

Here's my attempt:

```
    $results = $wpdb->query("UPDATE points SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE userid= %d", $theDynamicUserID);
```

That is giving the following error:

```
[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;%d&#039; at line 1]<br /><code>UPDATE points SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE userid= %d</code>
```

EDIT:
These Stack Exchange posts seem to hint that it's possible but I can't get the syntax right:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973380/sql-how-to-increase-or-decrease-one-for-a-int-column-in-one-command

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259155/increment-value-in-mysql-update-query

Comment: I maybe incorrect but from what I remember, [Arithmetic Operators](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-operators/sql-arithmetic-operators.php) in SQL only work with select. You'll need to first get the user from the DB, if exists add +1 to the upvotes, if not create a new row with upvotes set to 1

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Hi! This blog post seems to hint that it's possible but I can't get it to work: 

http://myblog.isdarn.sexy/update-values-incrementally-with-wpdb-in-wordpress-database/ 

If I need to use your method with a select statement first, can I do that somehow in the same query or do I need two separate queries? And if I need two separate queries, how do I call the second one only after the first one has completed?

Comment: You are correct, going by the posts you added in the edit its possible, posted an answer that will work. You were missing a prepare, thats why your sql query failed because %d was never handled the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed that you are missing a prepare.

Your code should look like this

```
$results = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('UPDATE points SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE userid= %d', $theDynamicUserID));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Seems like this is a bad idea:

I seem to have solved this by constructing the query first like this:

```
$theQuery = "UPDATE points SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE userid = '".$theDynamicUserID."'";

$results = $wpdb->query($theQuery);
```

Comment: STOP! don't use this!. This opens you to sql injection. You must use prepare! see my answer. What you did was pass a variable as is to your sql query, this is a BIG NO NO in sql, always use prepare!

Comment: Thanks, will do!